# Uploading files to Glacier using AWS S3 v/s S3 Glacier upload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Standard S3 console supports uploading files and changing storage type, but in S3 Glacier we need to create a vault, and console support is not provided. let's say if I selected the S3 Glacier storage class in standard S3 upload, how it's different from Glacier, will it internally create a vault? is there any price variation?

Uploading to Glacier via Amazon S3 storage classes looks simple and easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different types of Glacier.

The **'original' Amazon Glacier** uses vaults and jobs. Quite frankly, it is awful to use. It's bearable if you are using a software package that knows how to use Glacier, but it is not a pleasant experience. For example, even just *listing* the contents of a vault requires waiting for a job to run, and then results need to be retrieved.

Using **Glacier as a Storage Class in Amazon S3** is a much more pleasant way to use Glacier. You can use all standard S3 commands and utilities and it gives immediate feedback when you list objects. The only thing that takes time is retrieving an object that is in a Glacier storage class.

Plus, the `Glacier` and `Glacier Deep Archive` storage classes are **cheaper than Glacier itself!** I'd like to prove this, but the [pricing page for Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/glacier/pricing/) now redirects to S3 pricing so it's not possible to see how much it costs!

**Bottom line:** Use S3 storage classes, not the old 'Glacier' service that uses Vaults.