# Can AWS DMS have S3 Glacier as a target?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-dms, amazon-glacier

I didn't find any documentation to support that S3 Glacier is a supported target nor that it isn't. S3, however, is a valid target.

When S3 Glacier is the desired target, can we transfer directly to it, or do we need lifecycle policies to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my previous projects, it transfers to S3 with `Standard` storage class.

What you have to do is to make a [transitioning s3 lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html) from what you have thoughts.

Still, the best way of uploading to `Glacier` is over **S3 storage classes**, you can check John's comment about the reason behind: [Uploading files to Glacier using AWS S3 v/s S3 Glacier upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68482414/uploading-files-to-glacier-using-aws-s3-v-s-s3-glacier-upload)